# Simple Spring MVC App not deploying

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring MVC novice having some troubles deploying a simple application. I have a UserController class

```
    package net.fluidinnovations.controllers;

import net.fluidinnovations.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author net.fluidinnovations
 */
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/getUser")
    public ModelAndView getUser(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("user");
        User u = new User();
        u.setId(4);
        model.addObject(u);
        return model;
    }
```

An IndexController class

```
package net.fluidinnovations.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
/**
 *
 */
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="net.fluidinnovations.controllers" />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />



</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

The message I get while trying to deploy is:

In-place deployment at C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IssueTracking\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IssueTracking\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The module has not been deployed.

My index.jsp contains a simple:

```
<a href="/getUser">Get User!</a>
```

which should redirect to a user.jsp page containing the code to display {user}

Not sure why its not deploying, any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you should only return the model in the controller method? Shoudn't it return the output view? And while debugging it raises no error?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to your `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        <init-param> <!-- **Add this** -->
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>Path/To/ServletContext/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it was a simple mistake on my end. I was not including the necessary namespace files and their corresponding schemaLocations in the dispatcher-servlet.xml, namely:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">"
```